# Redirect pages based on login Roles

Tags: angularjs

In my application i have to redirect pages based on login roles
 My login controller

```
app.controller('LoginController',function(loginService, $rootScope,$scope, $http,$location) {

     $scope.login = function () {
        $scope.log=loginService.getLogin( $scope.emailId , $scope.password).
         then(function (response) {
            console.log($scope.log);
            console.log(response)
                     if (response.data.LoginVerificationResult.length === 0) {
                        alert('details are not Available for this emailId');
                        $scope.error=true;
                     } else {
                         $rootScope.name=response.data.LoginVerificationResult[0].UserName;


                         sessionStorage.setItem("User Id",response.data.LoginVerificationResult[0].UserID);
                         sessionStorage.setItem("UserName",response.data.LoginVerificationResult[0].UserName);
                         sessionStorage.setItem("UserType",response.data.LoginVerificationResult[0].UserType);

                            $scope.UserType = sessionStorage.getItem("UserType");
                            console.log($scope.UserType +"from login controller")
                         //$location.path('/dashboard')
                            if ($scope.UserType =='Doctor') {
                                $location.path('/empRegister')
                            }
                            else ($scope.UserType =='Patient') {
                                $location.path('/patientRegister')
                            }

                     }

         });
     };
});
```

My RouteProvider

```
app.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/login/login.html',
        controller : 'LoginController'

    }).when('/patientRegister', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/patientRegister/patientRegistration.html',
        controller : 'patientRegisterCtrl'

    }).when('/empRegister', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/hrRegister/empRegistration.html',
        controller : 'empRegisterController'

    }).when('/updateProfile', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/profileUpdate/update.html',
        controller : 'profileUpdate'

    }).when('/editprofile1', {
        templateUrl : 'app/components/profileUpdate/editprofile1.html',
        controller : 'profileUpdate'

    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : "/"
    });
} ])
```

From the above code it is working fine is this the right way what i am doing.If there is any alternative please suggest me

Comment: seems alright but why you are using separate forms for updating i mean update.html and editprofile1.html
i think there should be one form.

Comment: @MasoodRehman both are different functionalities

Comment: @MasoodRehman i wnat to know how to restrict acess based on roles can u provide me one example

Comment: @LinhPham i wnat to know how to restrict acess based on roles can u provide me one example

Comment: You can try to use service instead putting `if else` in your controller. ---- Example: `$location.path(services.roleDirector(userRole)); ` where `services.roleDriector()` will return a string which is the route you gonna redirect user to.

Comment: @LinhPham if possible can u tell me clearly, I am very new to angular so only  i am asking,Thanks in advance.

Comment: Generically you are doing it right, I just tell you a way to improve your code. Make it cleaner by using `service` in angular. That how controller supposed to be, as clean as possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can mention the role required for all state while defining states

```
$routeProvider.
        .when('/updateProfile', {
             templateUrl : 'app/components/profileUpdate/update.html',
             controller : 'profileUpdate',
             data:{ role:"admin"}
        }).when('/editprofile1', {
             templateUrl : 'app/components/profileUpdate/editprofile1.html',
             controller : 'profileUpdate',
              data:{ role:"user"}   
         })
```

Then you can listen route change event.

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function(e,next, current) { 
        var user ={}  // user object from any model
        if(user.role!=next.data.role){
             // do stuff you want  
        }
 });
```

Comment: how to get this values data:{ role:"admin"} and data:{ role:"user"}

Comment: These values will be static, you have to decide which state is accessible by which role. Say you want admin to access profile page and mention role :"user" .

Comment: one main problem is if i login as a doctor url will be http://localhost:8085/HMS/#/empRegister  doctor page will open, If i change the  empRegister to patientRegister in url  then patient page will open how to restrict this, I am very new to angular so only asking ...

Comment: Do you have user object on $rootScope or $scope.  having user role.?

Comment: ya i am having userType